# What is the average height in the NBA?

Tags: basketball, statistics, nba

Personally, I'm curious what the mean, median, and mode average heights are in the NBA. From what I can find it looks like [the mean average is about 6'7”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_in_sports), but I can't find any trace of median or mode averages in inches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the data at the NBA's great [stats page](http://stats.nba.com/league/player/#!/bio), I put together:

[image: NBA Player Heights]

This indeed has a mean just over 6'7".
Mode as indicated is 6'9".
Median is 6'7".
And a standard deviation of about 3.5" inches just for good statistical completeness (even looks loosely normal, which is a tad surprising).

Would be nice to break down by position (or limit it to starters), but the wouldn't do that for me despite suggesting it would.  Unfortunately there also was no minutes played option.

Gotta be pretty tall, eh!?!

Comment: Why is it surprising the distribution is (approximately) normal?

Comment: Aside: I suspect these are "reported" heights rather than  "actual" heights. Kevin Durant is reported at 6'9" but is actually 6'10 3/4". http://www.cbssports.com/nba/news/the-great-debate-is-over-kevin-durant-finally-admitted-his-real-height/

Comment: @Philip Kendall, good question to challenge, and maybe I should reconsider including that thought.  I felt like positions might invite more of a multimodal result (though there's a lot of overlap), and tended to expect a slight skew right due to only 2 of 5 positions being highly emphasized on height (at least when I watched more, maybe it's changed more now)... and the rarity of taller heights in the population.